# Fix bad image quality Pillow Tkinter macOS - Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library, resolution

I'm building a GUI app in python with Tkinter and I'm using the `Pillow` module to add images. I just moved on to a new MacBook Pro with a better screen resolution than my previous laptop and noticed the resolution of the images on the GUI is very bad. Even if the original PNG file quality is okay.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

global_frame = Frame(root, border=10)
global_frame.grid()

img = Image.open("/Users/marinnagy/Documents/image.png")
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

Label(global_frame, image=img_tk).pack()
Label(global_frame, text="I am a label").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the result with a 70x15px image:

[image: first example]

I tried to use a bigger image (700x150px) and downscale it by adding `img = img.resize((70, 15))` just after opening the image file. I also tried to add the `Image.LANCZOS` option but the result is the same, if not worst:

[image: second example]

Do you know what's wrong and how I can display a good quality image in tkinter on macOS?
Maybe a specific file format or another way to open the file?

EDIT:
I saw a [similar issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261534/450321) where the whole window resolution (image, label, button...) is low on macOS. This problem can be fixed by adding `NSHighResolutionCapable` parameter to the info.plist file. I checked but didn't find any similar thing for the image rendering, maybe that can help.

Comment: Can you open the image using the normal `tk.PhotoImage(...)` method? If so, use it to check if the image quality drops from `PIL` or `tkinter`. Right now it's possible that `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` is lowering the quality or it's possible that `tkinter` can't properly display the image.

Comment: Same result with ```PhotoImage(file="/Users/marinnagy/Documents/image.png")```, so the problem probably don't comes from PIL

Comment: That would mean that something doesn't work quite right right `tk.PhotoImage` or `tk.Label`. Can you try using `tk.Canvas` instead of `tk.Label`? I think it has the highest chance of working. If that doesn't work, then the problem is rooted somewhere in `tkinter`, and there is little chance of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just testet one of my apps on my mac 10.14 but on a bit older MacBook

Any yeah, I'd say the quality is bit lower, but it's hard to tell as I had to create screenshots on windows and pc to compare.

anyways, maybe this helps:

```
from PIL import Image

file = 'myfile.png'
img = Image.open(file)
small = (70, 15)
img.thumbnail(small)
```

Can't test it at the moment, but I was told that the thumbnail function on a PIL Image creates higher quality outputs.

Comment: The quality is still low with the ```thumbnail``` function. I think the problem comes from Tkinter or macOS and not PIL as the quality is also low without using PIL (see @TheLizzard comment)

Answer (score 0):

I've use this snippet of code to solve the problem of bad image resolution in Tkinter, it may help you

```
import ctypes

# Fixe image bad resolution
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```

Comment: Your code works in Windows, but OP is using MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

to:

```
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img).resize((70, 15)))
```

Comment: Already tried as mentioned in the question, didn't fix the issue